# Custom UITableViewCell's content is overlapped by delete button in editing mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode9

Environment: Xcode + Swift 4

I following the tutorial [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1) to create a app that using UITableView to show the meals, entering editing mode to delete meals, and other functions.

My problem is when I enter editing mode, the right-most star is overlapped by the delete button:

[image]

The tutorial says

> To fix this, you need to lay out the cell using nested stack views and Auto Layout constraints; however, that is left as an exercise for the reader.

The five stars are embedded in a custom horizontal stack view. And the horizontal stack view and a label are embedded in a vertical stack view.

The image view has following constraints:

[image]

And the vertical stack view has following constraints:

[image]

I try to add a new constraint on the vertical stack view to solve the problem:

[image]

But the right-most star will be shrunk:

[image]

How to prevent the right-most star from being overlapped or shrunk by the delete button?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are the stars also image views?

Comment: Each star is a UIButton

Comment: I see, did my answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a trailing constraint to the horizontal stack view should work. You just need to adjust the stars.

First, set the stack view's `distribution` to `.fillEqually` so that all the stars in it has the same width.

Then, set the stars' `contentMode` to `.scaleAspectFit` so that they don't look stretched and will only shrink in size while preserving the aspect ratio.